# Is it dangerous to give an application administrator privileges in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, privileges

I am using a 3rd party application for personal use. As I have issues with it I contacted the tech support who told me to launch it with admin privileges.

As far as I know it is quite dangerous to give admin privileges to an application that shouldn't need it, but tech support is swearing that it is a normal thing.

Am I right in being reluctant?

---

The computer in question is for personal usage, so I don't have a company policy to follow, but my personal work can deal with sensitive data. The application is a popular game and I prefer not to give its name here.

Comment: If tech support says it should run as admin then it probably needs admin rights like so many other software.

Comment: Give it a try if the tech support is someone whom you trust.

Comment: This game worked fine on a different computer, but I don't know if it is relevant to put that in the question.

Comment: (1) You’re using a game *for work?*  What is your job?  (2) An application can do some damage if you run it under your privileges, so you shouldn’t be running it at all if you don’t trust the author.  You have to decide *how much* you trust the author, and, since you’re not telling us any details, we can’t help you decide that.  (3) I agree with JakeGould: this seems very suspicious for a game.  Is tech support willing to tell you what the application does that requires privileges?  (3a) If this tech support for the developer or your “work”?  (4) Can you run it in a VM?

Comment: @Scott: (1) it was a mistake, I corrected my question (before your edit but after JakeGould's quote), I am using the game for gaming, but I also do personal work on the same computer.

Comment: @Scott: (2) can you detail what changes between the two modes? It would make a perfectly valid answer. I don't need you to decide for me, just to explain me how things work. (3) no, tech support don't want to explain me anything (4) I haven't tried. I can run it the normal way, with normal privileges, and it kinda work except it is buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is dangerous, but there's not really anything you as an end user can do about it if you want to use this software (the fact that tech support considers this 'normal' means it's a known issue on their end which hasn't been addressed by the development team, so no amount of you complaining is likely to change anything).

If the game itself has to run with admin privileges and there's no way around it, then that's a red flag and you should be avoiding it (no matter how popular it is), because that usually means it's using a rootkit or similar technology to deal with cheaters (which is in and of itself a questionable but moderately standard practice) or that there's an design problem with the software itself that the company does not want to fix (an MMO I used to play had the second issue, the client created a folder directly under `C:\` at runtime for storing temporary files, and as a result you either had to have things set up just right or run the game as an admin to make it work).

If it's just the installer having to run with admin privileges, I wouldn't be too worried.  Most installers need this to some extent, although it is reasonably unusual for one to have to be manually run it as administrator (though not unheard of, the primary software product of the company I work for is like this, largely because it does a few things that regular UAC elevation won't allow).

Comment: Worth pointing out if the application is not working, and the suggested resolution to the application not working, is to run the application as an Administrator there likely is a reason.  Some of the content in this answer is extremely speculative, there are lots of legitimate reasons, an application might need elevated permissions.

Comment: As it is now the software works... But not always. The game crashes randomly on some occasions, and sometimes goes alright, so I doubt it really has to have admin privileges to work, but as it is the solution offered by the tech support I am considering it. It is not just the installer that has to run with admin privileges: the solution offered is to run everything as admin.

Comment: @AnneAunyme - There are certain UPlay titles that if purchased through Steam, will only work if you launch Steam/UPlay, and the title as an Administrator.  *Since you don't want to provide specifics.  You are only going to get generic answers.*  Which likely will eventually cause the question to be protected due to the low-quality answers that will be submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound: I can provide specifics, I just don't want to give the name of the game. Is it that much an issue?

Comment: If you want a detailed answer, that goes beyond just generic devices, it is indeed an issue

Comment: @Ramhound: I am not asking about how to fix the game, just about how bad running a software in admin mode can get. If I name the thing I will get answers as "I know this program, you can trust it", or "have you tried to do X to fix your issue?". Those are not the answers I am looking for here.